# Corrupted download in AngularJs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download

I am trying to download a file using [FileSaver.js](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjsnOOmrLfIAhWJyRQKHZcSDDo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Feligrey%2FFileSaver.js%2F&usg=AFQjCNGfot02xOW1nkB4y3OnKpH3Ca2hdg&sig2=sbcanYiMv93Ppa-Lk6pSGw&bvm=bv.104819420,d.bGg), but I get a corrupted file whenever I hit download button.

App is backed by a PHP REST service, and using cURL from command line confirms that REST is working OK.

Here is last version of pseudo-code that I use for downloading:

```
// Let str be the data received from $http promise
// This code is run in a "then" callback

var arr= new Uint8Array(str.length);
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    arr[b]=str.charCodeAt(i);
};
var blob = new Blob([arr], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
saveAs(blob, "AFileName");
```

It just corrupts file.

I also tried without applying the `Uint8Array`, and giving `str` directly to `Blob`. As you guessed, it failed too.

I am writing server and client myself, so I can change anything in them. But the thing is I want to handle downloads client-side, and I just can't redirect users to file URL to download it, because REST needs authentication and that token only lives within Angular app. It would not be a good choice to change server just to handle file downloads without authentication.

The REST has URLs like `/files/:id` that when accessed, gives file content as a regular HTTP file download (tested with cURL as said above). Could `$http` be the problem? Somehow forcing some kind of encoding or some assumptions on received data. I don't have much experience in Angular, anyway.

Comment: @ArtjomB Is saying "Thanks" against rules here?

Comment: You could say that: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266187), but don't go and remove these things from old post. That might give them unwanted attention. Also, when you go about doing this, you should fix everything in the post. The reason I did this edit was because another user suggested the PHP tag for your question which seemed wrong since you've said you tested that part and it works. I then rejected their edit with an edit of my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was me :)

I had to specify `responseType: "arraybuffer"` for `$http` then give `str` directly to `Blob`.

Fixed code

```
// Let str be the data received from $http promise
// This code is run in a "then" callback
// Make sure to specify "responseType: "arraybuffer"" for $http

var blob = new Blob([str], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
saveAs(blob, "AFileName");
```

I was changing `responseType` in wrong place.

Comment: Can you specify where exactly you added responseType. I am adding it like this   queryObject = $resource(path, {}, {
        get: {
          method: 'GET',
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
          }
        }
      });

Comment: @Achyut I did not use `$resource`, I used `$http` itself. You may search on how to give `$http` parameters to `$resource` I think.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was going crazy trying to find out why my downloads were all corrupted.

Comment: Can anyone help me out with this? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396959/downloaded-document-getting-corrupted-using-blob-method-in-angularjs

Comment: You set me on the right track with the `responseType`.  On my side, I had to use `responseType: "blob"`.  It also prevented me to create the blob manually.