# How to return an Excel file from ASP.NET Core Web API web-app?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In similar questions, with this code works to download a PDF:

> I'm testing with local files (.xlsx, .pdf, .zip) inside the Controller folder.

[Similar Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853072/how-to-return-file-from-asp-net-5-web-api)

```
[HttpGet("downloadPDF")]
public FileResult TestDownloadPCF()
{
   HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult
   (System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Controllers/test.pdf"), "application/pdf")
    {
      FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
    };
   return result;
}
```

[image: This works great!]

But when another file?, for example an Excel File(.xlsx) or ZIP File(.zip), testing does not work properly.

Code :

```
[HttpGet("downloadOtherFile")]
public FileResult TestDownloadOtherFile()
{
  HttpContext.Response.ContentType = 
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Controllers/test.xlsx"), 
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
  {
    FileDownloadName = "otherfile"
   };
  return result;
}
```

Result:
[image]

I also did tests with the following Content-Type:

- "Application / vnd.ms-excel"
- "Application / vnd.ms-excel.12"

Getting the same result.

**Which is the right way to return any file type?**

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You need to add a `Content-Disposition` header with `attachment` type

Comment: add HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add ("Content-disposition", "attachment");
But get the same result.

Comment: We read the xls file into a byte array and return it as a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: set the charset to utf-8?

Comment: Download Excel file in reactjs  -->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73421257/8621764

Answer (score 15):

My (working) solution:

- I've got a class that dynamically creates an XLSX file using EPPlus.Core.

  - This returns a `FileInfo` for the generated file's path.

This is what is in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public async Task<FileResult> Get()
{
    var contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    // "items" is a List<T> of DataObjects
    var items = await _mediator.Send(new GetExcelRequest());

    var fileInfo = new ExcelFileCreator(contentRootPath).Execute(items);
    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);

    const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

    var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(bytes, contentType)
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileInfo.Name
    };

    return fileContentResult;
}
```

And here is what I have in Angular2:

```
downloadFile() {
    debugger;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('responseType', 'arraybuffer');

    let url = new URL('api/excelFile/test', environment.apiUrl);

    return this.http
        .get(url.href, {
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer
        })
        .subscribe((response) => {
            let file = new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
            let fileName = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
            saveAs(file, fileName);
        },
        err => this.errorHandler.onError(err)
        );
}
```

Comment: The contentType of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue.  My issue was being caused by the client request, **not** the server response. I solved it by adding a response content type to my Get request's header options.  Here is my example in Angular 2.

Request from client (Angular 2) **requires filesaver.js library

```
this._body = '';

    let rt: ResponseContentType = 2; // This is what I had to add ResponseContentType (2 = ArrayBuffer , Blob = 3)
        options.responseType = rt;
    if (url.substring(0, 4) !== 'http') {
        url = config.getApiUrl(url);
    }

    this.http.get(url, options).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            let mediaType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
            let blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: mediaType });
            let filename = 'test.xlsx';
            fileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
        });
```

Server side code. (.net core)

```
    [HttpGet("{dataViewId}")]
    public IActionResult GetData(string dataViewId)
    {
        var fileName = $"test.xlsx";
        var filepath = $"controllers/test/{fileName}";
        var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        return File(fileBytes, mimeType, fileName);
    }
```

here are the references if you want to see.

[Corrupted download in AngularJs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051467/corrupted-download-in-angularjs-app)

[C# File Download is Corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804245/c-sharp-file-download-is-corrupt)

Comment: Download Excel file in reactjs  -->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73421257/8621764

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of how you can download a file, you can model your scenario of downloading an Excel file after it:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromServices] IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Controllers", "TextFile.txt");
    return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", fileDownloadName: "Readme.txt");
}
```

If the file is in the `wwwroot` folder, you could do something like below instead:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return File(virtualPath: "~/TextFile.txt", contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8", fileDownloadName: "Readme.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NPOI

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace export_excel.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ExportExcelController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public ExportExcelController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        // https://localhost:5001/ExportExcel/Export
        // https://localhost:5001/static-file/employee.xlsx
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Export")]
        public IActionResult Export()
        {
            List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee{ emp_code = "152110032", Name = "Nguyen Hong Anh", Phone = "0909998789" },
                new Employee{ emp_code = "152110055", Name = "Tran Phuong Dung", Phone = "0909993456" },
                new Employee{ emp_code = "152110022", Name = "Do Bich Ngoc", Phone = "0909991237" },
                new Employee{ emp_code = "152110025", Name = "Tran Thu Ha", Phone = "0909990987" },
            };
            // New workbook.
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            // New worksheet.
            ISheet sheet = wb.CreateSheet();
            // Write to sheet.
            // Tạo row
            var row0 = sheet.CreateRow(0);
            // At first row, merge 3 columns.
            // Create cell before merging.
            row0.CreateCell(0);
            CellRangeAddress cellMerge = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2);
            sheet.AddMergedRegion(cellMerge);
            row0.GetCell(0).SetCellValue("Employee information");
            // Ghi tên cột ở row 1
            var row1 = sheet.CreateRow(1);
            row1.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("emp_code");
            row1.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("fullname");
            row1.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Phone");
            // Traversaling array, then write continous.
            int rowIndex = 2;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                // Init new row.
                var newRow = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
                // set values.
                newRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(item.emp_code);
                newRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(item.Name);
                newRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(item.Phone);
                // Increase index.
                rowIndex++;
            };
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists("c:\\myfiles\\employee.xlsx"))

            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\myfiles\employee.xlsx", FileMode.CreateNew);
                wb.Write(fs);
            }
            var path = Path.Combine(@"c:\myfiles\employee.xlsx");
            return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8", fileDownloadName: "employee.xlsx");
        }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string emp_code;
        public string Name;
        public string Phone;
    }

}
```

File `Startup.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace export_excel
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            // Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @"c:\audio\")),
            // Path.Combine(@"c:\audio\")),
            Path.Combine(@"c:\myfiles")),
                RequestPath = "/static-file"
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

You can use 1 of 2 ways, go to

```
https://localhost:5001/ExportExcel/Export
```

or

```
https://localhost:5001/static-file/employee.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// imports
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
   // function to download file
  const downloadExcelFileFun = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        `https://yourapp.test.com/api/v1/myexcelfile/demoExcelfile`,
        {
          // api payload data if any
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer TOKEN_STRING`,
          },
          responseType: "blob",
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // the res.data is of type blob
        FileSaver.saveAs(res.data, "exampleFile.xlsx");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          downloadExcelFileFun();
        }}
      >
        Download xLsx File
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```