# Running a powershell script through a web api, want response of that api as a excel file which is generated by ps1 script

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web api, through which I execute powerShell script Which create excel file with required data(audit log) into local System... But what I want is to get excel file as a response of that api. How can I achieve this?

My Powershell Script Code:-

```
# Create the session to Exchange Online
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Uri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/  -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

# Import the Exchange Online commands
Import-PSSession $Session
$csvFile = "C:\Reports\auditlog2.csv"
# Setup our start and end dates to pull back events
#$start = Get-Date
$end = Get-Date
$start = $end.AddDays(-1)
$i = 1;
$startTime = Get-Date
do
{
$AuditData = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $start -EndDate $end -RecordType SharePointFileOperation -ResultSize 5000 -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -SessionId "ExtractLogs" -SiteIds siteid
$ConvertedOutput = $AuditData | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
$ConvertedOutput | SELECT CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-csv $csvFile -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force 
Write-Host $i++ . $AuditData.Count
$i = $i + 1;
}
Until($AuditData.Count -eq 0)

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

My Web Api Code:-

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        // Add your path or relative one
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"C:\Reports\spauditapi-Modified\spauditapi-master\SPAuditApi\Shell_Script\ReportGenerationforPermission.ps1");
        //pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"../Shell_Script/ReportGenerationforPermission.ps1");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        //Collection <psobject/> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        var results = pipeline.Invoke();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: General Idea - Either script returns the Path to the file it created. Or you should know it before hand (i.e. Pass a path to script where it should create the file). Then after the File is created - read bytes & use as ResponseStream body.

Comment: Yeah i am specifying the path where the file is being created, in my Powershell script.

Comment: @AmardeepGupta You would need possibly this module to convert your output to a excel file instead of a CSV : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.2 then your API should return a FileContentResult instead of a string (see first code sample in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112330/934946 )