# Error Downloading Excel From Angular with Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi, filesaver.js

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to download an excel from the asp.net core web api using angular 7.

I have followed the article, 
[Return Excel file from asp.net core web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877195/how-to-return-an-excel-file-from-a-webapi-asp-net-core/44112330)

But the excel is corrupt when downloaded via angular. It's working fine and opening when I checked with Postman.

Please Assist,

Here is my Web Api Core Action Method,

```
[HttpGet("{report:bool}", Name = nameof(GetAllEventsExcel))]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllEventsExcel(
            [FromRoute] bool report,
            [FromQuery] PagingOptions pagingOptions,
            [FromQuery] SortOptions<Event, EventEntity> sortOptions,
            [FromQuery] SearchOptions<Event, EventEntity> searchOptions,
            CancellationToken ct)
        {
            pagingOptions.Offset = pagingOptions.Offset ?? _defaultPagingOptions.Offset;
            pagingOptions.Limit = pagingOptions.Limit ?? _defaultPagingOptions.Limit;

            var events = new PagedResults<EventReport>
            {
                Items = Enumerable.Empty<EventReport>()
            };

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var canSeeAllEvents = await _authzService.AuthorizeAsync(
                    User, "ViewAllEventsPolicy");
                if (canSeeAllEvents.Succeeded)
                {
                    events = await _event.GetAllForExcelAsync(pagingOptions, sortOptions, searchOptions, 0, ct);
                }
                else
                {
                    var userId = await _user.GetUserIdAsync(User);
                    events = await _event.GetAllForExcelAsync(pagingOptions, sortOptions, searchOptions, Convert.ToInt64(User.Identity.Name.Split('@')[0]), ct);
                }
            }

            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

            var fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(events.Items.GenerateExcel("Event"), contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = "Event.xlsx"
            };

            return fileContentResult;
        }
```

Angular Service,

```
getReport(reporturl: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(reporturl, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
            .pipe(
                // tap(data => console.log('getEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

Excel Download Button Click in Angular,

```
handleExcelDownload(data) {
    this.eventService.getReport(`${data}/true`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
          let mediaType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
          let blob = new Blob([response], { type: mediaType });
          let filename = 'event.xlsx';
          fileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
```

I checked the response in `console.log(response)` I'm getting some array buffer. And excel is downloaded, but when I open, I get error as

> Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to save the file in frontend.

Comment: As the message says, your file is to big to be downloaded. Try saving an empty dummy file to see if it works.

Comment: @alsami I even tried that. It fails. The Excel is just 10kb. Working fine on server download.

Comment: I Figured out. The problem is with the Excel App installed in my windows. The above code works fine. Thanks for the tip @alsami