# How to download rest api response content into excel using windows forms application c#

Tags: c#, excel, rest

I'm trying to download REST API response content as (original format) excel (.xlsx)

My request url is :- `https://www.connect2nse.com/extranet-api/member/file/download/1.0?segment=CM&folderPath=/Reports&filename=07141_AR1_Dec22.xlsx`

And I'm downloading the `07141_AR1_Dec22.xlsx` file.

So, I have used this method to return the response content

```
public static string DownloadFileName()
        {
            try
            {

                var client = new RestClient("https://www.connect2nse.com/extranet-api/member/file/download/1.0?segment=CM&folderPath=/Reports&filename=07141_AR1_Dec22.xlsx");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOweSUzI1NiJ9.eyJtZW1iZXJDZCI6IjA3MTQxIiwic3ViIjoiMDcxNDEiLCJsb2dpbklkIjoiYm5yaG8xIiwiaXNzIjoiYm5yaG8xIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc0ODA0NDE0LCJpYXQiOjE2NzQ4MDA4MTQsImp0aSI6ImEwY2U3NjNkLWY1OWUtNDY2Yy1hMmMwLTUwNGQwZDgzOTQwYiJ9.UCnkkvTTi9fZjWWak5deXgxPEqMG16FQP4Cy_u1cR0hQb-xQ4LAhbfpMtFz1WXQ4fz7ZmRhkR1i9JXY4w32lzQ");
                request.AddHeader("Cookie", "HttpOnly");
                var body = @"";
                request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                //Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

                return response.Content;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

And I'm calling this method in `btnDownload_Click` event in windows forms application

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string downloadfile = DownloadFileName();
            
            string _tradelogfile = Application.StartupPath + "\\07141_AR1_Dec22.xlsx";
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_tradelogfile, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(downloadfile);
            }
}
```

The `DownloadFileName` method is returning the output like below image

[image: response content]

So if I keep execute the program the file is downloading at specified location

Like below example

[image: downloaded file]

While I'm opening the file it is throwing warning errors and file is not opening like below

[image: File error 1]

[image: File error 2]

In the postman response also I'm getting the response like below image

[image: postman response]

And I have read this [article](https://community.transifex.com/t/how-to-download-an-excel-file-via-api/2818) for better understanding but it not helped to me.

Please suggest me where I did the mistake and  how to save(download) this REST API response content as excel format(.xlsx).

Should I use any dll or is my code issue ?

Please suggest.

Comment: The REST api response seems to be bytes of a `Zip file`, notice that it starts with "PK"..so it is not the binary content or office XML content that is normally expected for a excel .xlsx file.

Comment: Hi @AnandSowmithiran thanks for your comment and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877195/how-to-return-an-excel-file-from-asp-net-core-web-api-web-app) link and it is similar to my question but it is in asp.net core

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Actually I didn't understand your comment can please guide me how to save that response content as excel please help me

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran For the reference, modern-day .xlsx and .docx files _are_ Zip files with some XML internally, that's the definition of the format. Nothing wrong here thus.

Comment: got it @Sergey. the response from REST API should be treated as `byte[]` rather than string, I am not sure what is the type handling done by the Restclient package.

Comment: Yep, I think it's either treating the contents as a string or some issue with StreamReader (not reading to the end?) that causes trouble. I would start the debugging session by downloading the file outside of the application and comparing it to what's downloaded programmatically. If the encoding is correct but the size differs - it's most likely stream-related, otherwise it's related to the format or encoding mismatch between string and binary.

Comment: Hi @SergeyKudriavtsev thanks for your  comment can you please suggest me how to save(download) response (.xlsx) data as excel (because I have very less years of experience to understand this concept).

Comment: @Kumar There was nothing obviously wrong in your code - one would need to build and run your app to actually find the issue. Which is why in my previous comment I gave an advice to start the debugging by comparing that broken file that you get programmatically with the actual one that you can just download from your link - and then go from there depending on what you find.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev thanks for your comment and [this](https://gist.github.com/gazlu/1eded0c78d7bf0057cb609da752cb990) is what I'm looking for the answer.