# Downloaded document getting corrupted using Blob method in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, download, blob

Downloading a file used to work fine in my application until I upgraded Angular to the latest. Even now, the file is getting downloaded, but the issue is that it is getting corrupted. Upload file is working fine and if we check in the file server, the file will be intact. But upon download, I am getting corrupted file.

Html :

```
<td data-title="''">

    <a tooltip="Download CV" ng-hide="!talent.resumePath" tooltip-trigger tooltip-animation="false" tooltip-placement="bottom" ng-click="downloadResume(talent.id)" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="resume">
        <img src="../../img/DownloadIcon.png" /></a>
</td>
```

Controller :

```
downloadResume: function(employeeId) {
    return apiServices.getFileFromTalentPool('/talentpool/resume?id=' + employeeId)
 },
```

Where, getFileFromTalentPool is : https://hastebin.com/yivaterozi.js

Endpoint :

```
public FileResult GetResume(int id) {
    var result = _services.GetResume(id);
    if (result != null) {
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = result.ContentType;
        HttpContext.Response.Headers["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"] = "FileName";
        HttpContext.Response.Headers["FileName"] = result.FileDownloadName;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usually I download Doc files. I tried with a notepad file to see if it's the same. Strangely, I noticed that I am able to open the notepad file, but its content is manipulated to something like `[object Object]`. But for Doc files, it just shows:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like the code at https://hastebin.com/yivaterozi.js was updated from using deprecated `$http.success()` method to current `$http.then()`. Promise' success callback function (within `then` method) receives only one object argument: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Deprecated 'success' method got more arguments (data, status, headers) and `data` already contained raw data. When using `then()`, data is located under `data` property of response, so try to change your `$http` call to:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  url: fileurl,
  responseType:'arraybuffer',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + $rootScope.userInfo.access_token,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
}).then(function (data) {
  var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';
  var success = false;

  // Get the headers
  var headers = data.headers();
    ...
    ...
```

please note that headers are fetched correct here from the data object and not from the third argument (just add *var*, since we removed empty arguments).
Now in each place that you use *data*, change it to *data.data*, like:

```
// Try using msSaveBlob if supported 
var blob = new Blob([data.data], { type: contentType });
```

or just change argument *data* to *response* and add `var data = response.data;` anf modify headers getter to `headers = response.headers();`:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  cache: false,
  url: fileurl,
  responseType:'arraybuffer',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + $rootScope.userInfo.access_token,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';
  var success = false;

  // Get data
  var data = response.data;

  // Get the headers
  var headers = response.headers();
    ...
    ...
```